# Windows control needs to be clicked twice

Tags: c#, .net, windows, controls

I apologise in advance if there is any vagueness, but I am struggling with even knowing where to start with this one.

We have an app written in C# & .Net framework 4.6.2. installed at numerous customers working with out issue. At one customer all the 'OK' button controls need to be clicked twice rather than once to work. There are numerous different programs that don't have any common code, but still exhibit the same behaviour.

I am suspecting a windows issue rather than app, but done't know where to start. Could anyone point me in the right direction please?

cheers
Rich

Comment: doubt it is a windows issue.  you need to post some code

Comment: Obviously it's their Mouse driver or their mouse settings.

Comment: Do any of their other applications - not provided by you - show the same problem? As Jeremy intimated - have they tried changing the mouse, to rule out problems with that (I have several old ones where clicking is not reliable - clicks missed as well as multiple clicks with a single press)? Check in the Mouse settings (on Control Panel) under the "Buttons" tab - bottom option (at least in Windows 7) is "Turn On ClickLock" - make sure that is disabled - turning that on would require two clicks on a button to get the mouse up event.

Comment: Is it consistent and have you seen it yourself?

Comment: Usually these type issues has to do with the focus in Windows.  Clicking twice you first are the focus of the control and then you are able to actually do the click.  So it means that something in the program is taking the focus away from the control.  It may be another control that is overlaying the control (or even a hidden control).

Comment: update. It isn't just a mouse click - hitting return on the field does the same thing. The progam just calls the messagebox function.. it is consistent but only at this one client, ok at 70+ others. I haven't been able to see if for myself yet, they are still sorting out access.

Comment: it looks like a focus issue. When the box pops up there is no focus, click / hit 1 changes the focus to the button, click / hit 2 exits.